# Transferring money as I immigrate to Canada

Tags: taxes, canada, foreign-exchange

At the time of immigration I transferred my savings to US Dollars. Since then, I have additionally received some foreign inheritances in US Dollars. Now I want to transfer US Dollars to Canadian dollars. Do I have to show this transaction in my tax return? If so, how?

Comment: In which country do you live now?

Comment: Double post: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/83518/us-dollars-conversion-to-canadian-dollars

Comment: Possible duplicate of [US Dollars conversion to Canadian dollars](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/83518/us-dollars-conversion-to-canadian-dollars)

Answer (score 1):

In theory, when you obtained ownership of your USD cash as a Canadian resident [*resident for tax purposes, which is generally a quicker timeline than being resident for immigration purposes], it is considered to have been obtained by you for the CAD equivalent on that date.

For example if you immigrated on Dec 31, 2016 and carried $10k USD with you, when the rate was ~1.35, then Canada deems you to have arrived with $13.5k CAD. If you converted that CAD to USD when the rate was 1.39, you would have received 13.9k CAD, [a gain of $400 to show as income on your tax return].

Receiving the foreign inheritances is a little more complex; those items when received may or may not have been taxable on that day. However whether or not they were taxable, you would calculate a further gain as above, if the fx rate gave you more CAD when you ultimately converted it.

If the rate went the other way and you *lost* CAD-value, you may or may not be able to claim a loss. If it was a small loss, I wouldn't bother trying to claim it due to hassle. If it's a large loss, I would be very sure to research thoroughly before claiming, because something like that probably has a high chance of being audited.

Answer (score 0):

I think the general rule for Canada resident to receive foreign inheritance don't have tax effect and you don't have to declare it. It's a little different from US global tax regulation.

ref: [intuit.ca](https://turbotax.intuit.ca/tips/declaring-inherited-overseas-property-6225)